# Is redirection a best practice in microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am developing a microservice that accepts x-www-form-urlencoded content type and has some redirects to external URLs, is this a bad practice to have a redirection?

Comment: A redirection on the same site after a form submit is a normal technique to prevent double clicked submits. To redirect to an external site means traffic first reaches you. That might not be needed, might be used for statistics / dropping user state. But you have to ask yourself, why redirecting?

Comment: What kind of redirect are you talking about? Does  External Url mean that a service which is out of your environment or simply in your environment?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Out of our environment

Comment: Actually it is not a bad design or behavior if it is necessary. As I understand from your code your code behaves like a gateway and redirects request to external service render UI. If UI doesn't related to your environment you don't have any other choice

Answer (score 0):

The motive behind Microservices is to decentralize and decouple the program so that they can operate independently !

Redirection may be a bad thing here as it would be simple to just call that Microservice end points rather than redirecting from another microservice (Unless you want to main abstractions and avoid direct calling , which you can still do via Async communication for `e.g. via MQs such as RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka` )

*Re-direction would ultimately increase the HTTP calls eventually increasing unwanted traffic which you won't want !*

**I'd suggest to go through some theory which might be helpful for you to design & decide well**

https://microservices.io/

Comment: Here, we need to redirect as it is necessary, we will get a form post request from the user, we need to redirect to a external url that will render the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It dependens. Redirection is not a bad practice by itself. A microservice can perfectly communicates with either other microservices or external services if needed. It depends of your achitecture.